# Rails async execution of events like NATS or Kafka or AMQP without separate process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I'm trying to integrate NATS into a Rails server in order to process jobs. Since there isn't a good NATS based job system I'm going to reuse a standard gem like Que.

My process would be: nats message -> a Rails something doing pull_subscribe() and a blocking .fetch() -> inserts a job into Que (this could be any other gem eg delayed_job)

My question is how do I listen to NATS messages without yet another separate process? Can I have an initializer that does Thread.new { nats.pull_subscribe; nats.fetch } (which blocks)? If yes, what is the performance impact? Will a puma thread be blocked?